# Response time using aiohttp increases over time

Tags: python-3.x, semaphore, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have an API "localhost/service" that takes on average 2s to return when requested serially and about 8s when I set up 10 threads to request it in parallel. I wanted to replicate those numbers using asyncio, without threads. The way I decided to do that was following this [article's](https://pawelmhm.github.io/asyncio/python/aiohttp/2016/04/22/asyncio-aiohttp.html) code and setting the semaphore to 10. for the first 20 or so requests I get response times of 8s but after that the response times start increasing quite dramatically. I keep requesting the server using postman on the side and its consistently returning response times of 8s while this script using asyncio is reporting times of over a minute per request. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import time
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession

async def fetch(url, session):
    start = time.monotonic()
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        end = round(time.monotonic() - start, 4)
        print("response time: {}".format(end))
        return await response.read()


async def bound_fetch(sem, url, session):
    # Getter function with semaphore.
    async with sem:
        await fetch(url, session)


async def run(r):
    url = 'http://localhost:8080/service'
    tasks = []
    # create instance of Semaphore
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(10)

    # Create client session that will ensure we dont open new connection
    # per each request.
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        for i in range(r):
            # pass Semaphore and session to every GET request
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(bound_fetch(sem, url.format(i), session))
            tasks.append(task)

        responses = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        await responses

number = 10000
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

future = asyncio.ensure_future(run(number))
loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

Answer (score 0):

The article is quite outdated.

*aiohttp* has a 100 parallel connection limit by default, see [here](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#tcpconnector).

Basically you don't need a semaphore (its functionality is embedded into aiohttp itself) but should increase a connection pool size.

Comment: with or without the semaphore, the response times keep increasing. I tried recreating the same script using multiprocessing.dummy and it worked like a charm. Why does aiohttp keep increasing response times?

Comment: Did you increase `limit` parameter of `TCPConnector`?

Comment: I didnt even get to issue 100 requests. Response times start increasing on the 15th request already. Try executing the script I posted and change url to google for example, youll see what Im talking about

Comment: Man, check your code. I've run your unmodified example against a local server and see no performance degradation.