# Asyncio get with unique URLs slower than non-unique

Tags: python, url, unique, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have an asyncio function which calls `aiohttp.Clientsession` to get json data from many (10,000) URLs (code below).

During testing, I have simply been calling the async function with a list of urls:
`urls=[url1, url2, url3, url4, url5]*2000`

I have now achieved a speed of about 300 it/s with the above url variable.
However, it is about 10x slower when I try to run this with a complete list of 10,000 unique urls:
`urls=[url1, url2, ..., url10000]`

I am not sure why the unique url list is much slower. Maybe the asyncio maybe compares sessions to see if they are fetching the same thing and return the same value, instead of fetching a new value?

It seems as though [THIS IMPLEMENTATION](https://pawelmhm.github.io/asyncio/python/aiohttp/2016/04/22/asyncio-aiohttp.html) is robust and fast. I have even tried copying this but I get the same results: 300it/s with the non-unique list, and 30it/s with unique.

Perhaps there is something simple I am missing in the implementation of the function below.

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import tqdm.asyncio
from url_list import unique_urls

async def fetch(session, url, sem):
    async with sem, session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.json()

async def fetch_all(session, urls, loop):
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(100)
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(fetch(session, url, sem)) for url in urls]
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks,tq(tasks))

async def run(urls):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
        return await fetch_all(session, urls, loop)

async def tq(tasks):
    for f in tqdm.asyncio.tqdm.as_completed(tasks):
        await f

if __name__ == '__main__':
    len(unique_urls)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    calc_routes = loop.run_until_complete(run(unique_urls))
```

My unique and non-unique list are below:

```py
    nonunique_urls = [
               "https://arweave.net/ufeA5gLvBtf9vFt_HaLtZsOXIIN5cOfHB2c_DKTbOT8",
               "https://arweave.net/UHGKgIp9OAxBsAbR1px3Sqaq1kWqFvNfeEeT9VDeArY",
               "https://arweave.net/J8dxe4MHj1TRRaEI5wxiXP-ulqTn_z5NADlX19kVxew",
               "https://arweave.net/TuJ0uo6Gofe1cxaNIWwyx0RxjF5khkHTcwtdEu3m1BA",
               "https://arweave.net/nv0yKK7U_2T2a4KdC41BBPgOYAldJxyFmnjnavjMI5I"
           ] * 2000

    unique_urls=['https://arweave.net/ufeA5gLvBtf9vFt_HaLtZsOXIIN5cOfHB2c_DKTbOT8',
               'https://arweave.net/UHGKgIp9OAxBsAbR1px3Sqaq1kWqFvNfeEeT9VDeArY',
               'https://arweave.net/J8dxe4MHj1TRRaEI5wxiXP-ulqTn_z5NADlX19kVxew',
               'https://arweave.net/TuJ0uo6Gofe1cxaNIWwyx0RxjF5khkHTcwtdEu3m1BA',
               'https://arweave.net/nv0yKK7U_2T2a4KdC41BBPgOYAldJxyFmnjnavjMI5I',
               'https://arweave.net/a8cnY1xvM82d444JMSvzKO2qy7DCW73tFaFuNAkPzeg',
               'https://arweave.net/pfv8utICUpTHmvdM9bWxMyI8hHmJCf33bMw1F0nvXik',
               'https://arweave.net/oRAf9M7gG3mtraqzXh9XsCxbM675u3wxzYM5scL1keY',
               'https://arweave.net/2AiZNhPluj9jwdOOlIk_vqKYzhLwtJyLAT_7tdNvgVg',
                              ........]
```

Comment: There could be multiple reasons for this. One could be caching both on the client-side (your code) and server-side. This would make sense as you request the same 5 URLs. Another thing could be that the nonunique_urls are all fast (70ms) with a small response. The unique URLs could contain some slow requests skewing the results. I would collect the response time for all requests and analyze the result. Probably, you will find some pattern. Is the `unique_urls` list publicly available to reproduce your question?

Comment: I will setup a response time to measure this. I am quite sure it isn't just one (or a few) URLs that are slowing it down. It is likely the caching that you spoke of (unfortunately). You can check out 1000 of the urls here: https://pastebin.com/MuHnirvG . It is enough of the list to show the slow down in my experience

Comment: Tested the code and got the same behavior. Not sure if you can solve it and how to solve it. However, you can play with the connection limit, which is 100 to achieve some speed up. Also, the semaphore is apparently not needed anymore. Found that in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50805310/7947994) linking to the same article.

Comment: Yeah I tried pushing semaphore to 1000 (the max I think?) and also connection limit with `conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=1000)` and saw very small improvements. It seems difficult for me to measure the speed of each response, but I am using tqdm (a progress bar) and I can see it is pretty smooth the whole way to 100%. I'm going to put time into finding out how to improve speed instead of measuring the bad speed